# Redirect user to original url after login?

Tags: redirect, urls, login

I have a function that redirects users to the login page (home) if they're trying to access any other page without being logged in, here's how it works:

```
function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_home()){
        wp_redirect( get_option('home') );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restrict_access_if_logged_out', 3 );
```

Really simple and works fine, the problem is that is that I need to redirect them to the url they were trying to go to after they successfully log in, exactly like the WordPress backend works.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks all, I kind of used a bit of what everyone recommended so in the end my code looks like this:

```
function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_home()){
        wp_redirect( get_option('home') . '?redirect_to=' . esc_url($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restrict_access_if_logged_out', 3 );
```

And on my login form (I'm hardcoding my login form in my aplication thanks @Ashfame for letting me know about wp_login_form I had no idea it existed) I added this when user credentials are fine and they're ready to login:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to'])){
    wp_redirect($_REQUEST['redirect_to']);
    // wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to exit;
    exit;

} else {
    wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url') . '/groups/');
    exit;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help, I voted up everyone!

Comment: Hi Javier, in which file did you add these functions? Thanks.

Comment: In `functions.php`

Comment: You should call `exit()` or `die()` after `wp_redirect()`. Otherwise it's possible that code after `wp_redirect()` will execute, which can lead to bugs and security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 16):

You can do that easily. You just need to specify a redirection parameter.
If you are using a login link on the homepage to go to the login page, then @sisir's solution is correct.

`<?php echo wp_login_url( $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ); ?>`

If you are using a custom form on the frontpage, then inside the `<form>`, make sure you fill in a hidden field with the url to redirect

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>" />
```

And if you are using `wp_login_form()` to generate the form, then fill in a parameter - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form

```
<?php
$args = array(
        'echo' => true,
        'redirect' => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 
        'form_id' => 'loginform',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
        'id_username' => 'user_login',
        'id_password' => 'user_pass',
        'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
        'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
        'remember' => true,
        'value_username' => NULL,
        'value_remember' => false );

wp_login_form( $args );
?>
```

Change other parameters as per what you have or need.

Comment: i am using custom form, and i am using your provided hidden field solution, but in my case i am being redirected to url like this 'localhost/wordpress/localhost/wordpress/blog/someone'. any help?

Comment: i have got this, i am using double slash. so my solution is like this <?php echo '//' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>

Answer (score 7):

Try passing `the_permalink()` as the `$redirect` argument:

```
function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_home()){
        wp_redirect( the_permalink() );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restrict_access_if_logged_out', 3 );
```

EDIT:

Sorry, misunderstood your question originally. Try this:

```
function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_home()){
        $redirect = home_url() . '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . urlencode( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        wp_redirect( $redirect );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restrict_access_if_logged_out', 3 );
```

Note also: proper usage of `wp_redirect()` generally requires adding `exit;`, which I have added to my second example.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, the redirect needs to go to home, that's working fine I need some way to catch the original url and redirect the user there once he logs in.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question originally. I've added an edit that hopefully addresses your use case.

Answer (score 2):

this is my code that i use people to direct to wp login page. Then when logged in they returned back to where they were. But it is not home page but the wordpress login page where i setup custom login.

```
<?php echo wp_login_url( $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) ?>
```

You might wanna research with. Typically you will get the current url of a user by `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super late, but I made a post about exactly how to do this if any future people find this and need it:

http://www.ryanprejean.com/force-login-with-redirect-and-exceptions/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [answer].

Comment: Link is broken (April 2020).

Comment: I was able to access [the broken link with the Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190209073356/http://www.ryanprejean.com/force-login-with-redirect-and-exceptions/), in case anyone else needs the info.

Answer (score 0):

The [`login_redirect` filter hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) is a more complete and effective solution here. This way, you can offer different redirect paths for different levels of users, or maintain the redirect URL in the case of an error when logging in (i.e. Incorrect Password).

```
function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
  if(isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to'])){
    return $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
  }
  return admin_url();
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3 );

function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){
  if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_home()){
    $redirect = home_url() . '?redirect_to=' . esc_url($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    wp_redirect( $redirect );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restrict_access_if_logged_out', 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

It has not worked any of your answers but only adding a little thing, it worked!
Here my code:

```
function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
  if(isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to'])){
    return $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
  }
  return admin_url();
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3 );

function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){
  if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_home()){
    $redirect = home_url() . '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . esc_url($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
    wp_redirect( $redirect );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restrict_access_if_logged_out', 3 );
```

Only I added `/wp-login.php` in comparison to @Matt's response, but for me has been the key. Hope that helps! :)

**EDIT:

I detected an ERROR when you are FORCE wordpress to navegate in HTTPS. This method doesn't work because the redirection is in HTTP. For fix the problem I changed the function. This is the result:

```
function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){
  global $wp;
  $protocol='http';
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
    if (strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTPS'])=='ON')
      $protocol='https';
  if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_home() && ($wp->query_vars['pagename'] != 'downloads') ){
    $redirect = home_url() . "/wp-login.php?redirect_to= $protocol://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    wp_redirect( $redirect );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restrict_access_if_logged_out', 3 );
```

I check the protocol and then I deleted '`esc_url`' and added the correct protocol: `$protocol://`. Also I changed the `""`.

I'm based with [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801340/php-header-location-redirect-https-to-https-http-to-http).