# How to direct to any page?

Tags: urls

How to direct to login page and go to destination page?
for example: if user click any URL who that user not yet login, direct to login page.

After, sign in, user continue directly to page that user want. How to get URL, save in temporary trick in WordPress.

Code sample :

page 1 : `<a href="">Game List</a>`

page 2 : `if (is_user_logged_in()){\\here***how save this URL**//}else{go to login page}`

page login : `if login success go to **save this URL**`.

Any suggestion, please? Thank you

Comment: Have a look at This Post, I tested Chip's answer, I believe that's what your wanting: [Chip Bennett's Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/16005)