# Remember page before login page, redirect to that page after login

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, login

I have a woocommerce shop that only allows logged in users to make purchases. I have replaced my add to cart button with a "login" button if the user is not already logged in. This than brings them to the (my-account) page where they can choose to login or register.

However I was wondering if I could take this one step further and make it so wordpress remembers what page the user was on before they entered the login page. And if they login, it will redirect them back to that page.

I found this script which redirects users to the login page if they click on a product/page. And then if they login it takes them back to the page they were trying to enter. This is close to what I want to do, but instead of taking them to the login page before seeing a product. I want them to be able to see the product. Then click a button that takes them to the ((my-account page)) and if they login it redirects them back to the product page.

[Redirect user to original url after login?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16004/redirect-user-to-original-url-after-login)

Any help would be much appreciate. Function, plugins, anything.

Thanks!

Comment: How is your login form implemented? I don't see any code in your question :(

Comment: Its just the native "my-account" login form page that comes with woocommerce

Comment: All woocommerce login pages are the same accross most themes. Unless the theme changes it. Mine just uses the native woocommerce login form. 

Like: https://themes.woocommerce.com/storefront/my-account/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else looking for a solution to this. My boyfriend and I have solved it with the below script. Simply paste into your functions.php file for any woocommerce setup.

```
/** Log in redirect to previous page by portalpacific.net **/
// start global session for saving the referer url
function start_session() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'start_session', 1);

// get the referer url and save it to the session
function redirect_url() {
    if (! is_user_logged_in()) {
        $_SESSION['referer_url'] = wp_get_referer();
    } else {
        session_destroy();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_url' );

//login redirect to referer url
function login_redirect() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['referer_url'])) {
        wp_redirect($_SESSION['referer_url']);
    } else {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 1100, 2);

/** end here */
```

Thanks for getting us started Karen.

Comment: Using PHP sessions will cause problems on Ngix and Varnish with server caching. You can check the alternatives in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855246/woocommerce-redirect-customers-to-previous-page/57925021#57925021 Or simply download my plugin which among multiple settings has redirect to the previous page after WooCommerce login functionality: https://wordpress.org/plugins/extra-settings-for-woocommerce/

Comment: This worked for me, can you tell me if this code can even harm the cache via WP Rocket?

Answer (score 2):

You can use wordpress referrer function.
For example set referrer URL in session by clicking on add to cart button or any button to store previous URL. Once login or register success add Woocommerce success login redirect to that URL.

For more information read WordPress referrer URL read here;

[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_referer/](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer)

For Woocommerce login redirect read here;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342186/woocommerce-after-login-redirect