# Set redirect for need login

Tags: shortcode, redirect, login

**Hello**, I have this code so when I place the **[need_login]** shortcode on a page, it redirects users who are not logged in to a **Login page**. The problem with this is the that it redirects them to the default WordPress page. How can I add the **url** of the page I want them to be redirected to.

```
function shortcode_needLogin() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        auth_redirect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_redirect()` instead of `auth_redirect()` - make sure to call `exit()` right after `wp_redirect()`. Check out the codex for more info on [wp_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/).

Answer (score 0):

Great question.  As ScottM mentioned, you want to use wp_redirect() rather than auth_redirect.  Then within the `()`, you'll want to specify your target.

It always makes the most sense to me when I can see real code, so I'd encourage you to look at [Redirect user to original url after login?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16004/redirect-user-to-original-url-after-login) - there are multiple methods / code options, each shown there.